# Ionic 2 - Call function from controller in a service

Tags: function, service, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 project with a page home.html/home.ts and a service connectivity-service.ts. The service should check if the user is online or offline. On top of that in the service some listeners are added to watch if the user goes offline or comes online. Every page which uses the service should give functions to the service, which should be called onOnline/onOffline.

Here is my code for the connectivity-service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var Connection;

@Injectable()
export class ConnectivityService {

    onDevice: boolean;
    onOnlineFunction: any;
    onOfflineFunction: any;

    constructor(public platform: Platform) {
        this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the connectivity service
     * @param onOnlineFunction
     * @param onOfflineFunction
     */
    init(onOnlineFunction = null, onOfflineFunction = null){
        this.onOnlineFunction = onOnlineFunction;
        this.onOfflineFunction = onOfflineFunction;
        if(this.isOnline()){
            if(this.onOnlineFunction){
                this.onOnlineFunction();
            }
        }
        else{
            if(this.onOfflineFunction){
                this.onOfflineFunction();
            }
        }
        this.addConnectivityListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Check if the user is online
     * @return {boolean}
     */
    isOnline(): boolean {
        // Check if the user is on a device or on browser
        if(this.onDevice && Network.type){
            return Network.type !== Connection.NONE;
        }
        else{
            return navigator.onLine;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Watch online oberservable to check if the user comes online
     * @return {Observable<any>}
     */
    watchOnline(){
        return Network.onConnect();
    }

    /**
     * Watch offline oberservable to check if the user goes offline
     * @return {Observable<any>}
     */
    watchOffline() {
        return Network.onDisconnect();
    }

    /**
     * Add connectivity listeners to permanently check if the user goes on- or offline
     */
    addConnectivityListeners(): void {

        let onOnline = () => {

            if(this.onOnlineFunction){
                this.onOnlineFunction();
            }

        };

        let onOffline = () => {

            if(this.onOfflineFunction){
                this.onOfflineFunction();
            }

        };

        this.watchOnline().subscribe(() => {

            onOnline();

        });

        this.watchOffline().subscribe(() => {

            onOffline();

        });

        if(!this.onDevice){
            document.addEventListener('online', onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener('offline', onOffline, false);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the ionViewDidLoad function in my home.ts and the function which should be called when the user is online / comes online:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        this.connectivity.init(this.loadData);

    });

}

loadData(){
    // Here are some API calls and other things with other services
    // and also some allocations to some variables from home.ts
}
```

The problem is now that the service calls this function like it is a part of the service. So if the services which are used in this function are not imported into the connectivity service, it is not working. On top of that the allocations to the variables of home.ts are not working. Is there a way how I can call the given function in connectivity-service.ts like it is called in the home.ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`Function.Prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) inorder to ensure the `this` object remains that of the component.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    this.connectivity.init(this.loadData.bind(this));//here

});
```